# ScrollSpy with Om

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, scrollspy, om

I'd like to get [Om](https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Documentation) to work with ScrollSpy.

I'm currently using this code:

```lisp
(defn main-component
  [data owner]
  (om/component
    (dom/div
      #js {:className "col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main"}
      (dom/div
        #js {:className "main-panel"
             :data-spy "scroll"
             :data-target ".nav-sidebar"}
        "..."))))
```

```lisp
(defn sidebar-component
  [data owner]
  (om/component
    (dom/div
      #js {:className "container-fluid"}
      (dom/div
        #js {:className "row"}
        (dom/div
          #js {:className "col-sm-2 col-md-2 sidebar"}
          (dom/div
            #js {:className "nav-sidebar"}
            (dom/ul
              #js {:className "nav"}
              (dom/li nil (dom/a #js {:href "#thing-1"} "Thing 1"))
              (dom/li nil (dom/a #js {:href "#thing-2"} "Thing 2"))
              (dom/li nil (dom/a #js {:href "#thing-3"} "Thing 3"))
              )))))))
```

```lisp
(defn app-component
  "The top-level Om component."
  [data owner]
  (om/component
    (om/build
      (common/app-template
        (om/build sidebar-component data)
        (om/build main-component data))
      data)))
```

Currently, it seems to work up until Om / React.js re-renders the DOM. After that, ScrollSpy stops working. I think I know why. According to [Bootstrap ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy): "When using scrollspy in conjunction with adding or removing of elements from the DOM, you'll need to call the refresh method like so:"

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
  var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh');
});
```

What should I do? I think I want to hook into Om and tell it to call ScrollSpy as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to get this to work.

First, ScrollSpy needs to bind to the scrolling element, e.g. the body, not an element nested inside. So I removed the static attributes from the "main panel" shown above (e.g. `main-component`). Next, I show how I use scripting to bind to the body element.

Second, I added handlers for IDidMount and IDidUpdate as follows:

```lisp
(defn app-component
  [data owner]
  (reify
    om/IDidMount
    (did-mount
      [this]
      (.log js/console "did-mount")
      (-> (js/$ "body")
          (.scrollspy #js {:target ".nav-sidebar"})))

    om/IDidUpdate
    (did-update
      [this prev-props prev-state]
      (.log js/console "did-update")
      (-> (js/$ "body")
          (.scrollspy "refresh")))

    om/IRender
    (render
      [this]
      ; ...
      )))
```